# Piranha CMS - Creating a new MVC app - broken

Tags: asp.net-mvc, piranha-cms

i'm trying to integrate Piranha CMS into an existing MVC5 web app. 
I have followed the recommended route in http://piranhacms.org/docs/introduction/getting-started , it's all pretty simple stuff using Nuget.
After running the app i got a message stating the AutoMapper wasn't there, so added it through Nuget. All good so far.
Run it again and get this error:

"Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information."

here's the stack:

> [ReflectionTypeLoadException: Unable to load one or more of the
>   requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more
>   information.]
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes(RuntimeModule module) +0
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes() +4
>   System.Reflection.Assembly.GetTypes() +70
>   System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.AssemblyCatalog.get_InnerCatalog()
>   +167    System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.AssemblyCatalog.GetExports(ImportDefinition
>   definition) +11
>   System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.<>c__DisplayClass3.b__2(ComposablePartCatalog
>   catalog) +17    System.Linq.d__14`2.MoveNext()
>   +177    System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.CatalogExportProvider.InternalGetExportsCore(ImportDefinition
>   definition, AtomicComposition atomicComposition) +205
>
>   System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.InnerCatalogExportProvider.GetExportsCore(ImportDefinition
>   definition, AtomicComposition atomicComposition) +14
>
>   System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.ExportProvider.TryGetExportsCore(ImportDefinition
>   definition, AtomicComposition atomicComposition, IEnumerable`1&
>   exports) +39
>   System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.ExportProvider.TryGetExports(ImportDefinition
>   definition, AtomicComposition atomicComposition, IEnumerable`1&
>   exports) +23
>
>   System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.CatalogExportProvider.GetExportsCore(ImportDefinition
>   definition, AtomicComposition atomicComposition) +61
>
>   System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.ExportProvider.TryGetExportsCore(ImportDefinition
>   definition, AtomicComposition atomicComposition, IEnumerable`1&
>   exports) +39
>   System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.AggregateExportProvider.GetExportsCore(ImportDefinition
>   definition, AtomicComposition atomicComposition) +311
>   System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.ExportProvider.TryGetExportsCore(ImportDefinition
>   definition, AtomicComposition atomicComposition, IEnumerable`1&
>   exports) +39
>
>   System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.ExportProvider.TryGetExports(ImportDefinition
>   definition, AtomicComposition atomicComposition, IEnumerable`1&
>   exports) +23
>   System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.CompositionContainer.GetExportsCore(ImportDefinition
>   definition, AtomicComposition atomicComposition) +156
>   System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.ExportProvider.TryGetExportsCore(ImportDefinition
>   definition, AtomicComposition atomicComposition, IEnumerable`1&
>   exports) +39
>
>   System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.ExportProvider.GetExports(ImportDefinition
>   definition, AtomicComposition atomicComposition) +36
>
>   System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.ImportEngine.TryGetExports(ExportProvider
>   provider, ComposablePart part, ImportDefinition definition,
>   AtomicComposition atomicComposition) +44
>
>   System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.ImportEngine.TrySatisfyImportSubset(PartManager
>   partManager, IEnumerable`1 imports, AtomicComposition
>   atomicComposition) +155
>   System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.ImportEngine.TrySatisfyImportsStateMachine(PartManager
>   partManager, ComposablePart part) +439
>   System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.ImportEngine.TrySatisfyImports(PartManager
>   partManager, ComposablePart part, Boolean shouldTrackImports) +196
>   System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.ImportEngine.SatisfyImports(ComposablePart
>   part) +107
>   System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.<>c__DisplayClass2.b__0()
>   +26    System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.CompositionServices.TryInvoke(Action
>   action) +33
>   System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.ComposablePartExportProvider.Compose(CompositionBatch
>   batch) +841
>   System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.CompositionContainer.Compose(CompositionBatch
>   batch) +33
>   System.ComponentModel.Composition.AttributedModelServices.ComposeParts(CompositionContainer
>   container, Object[] attributedParts) +172
>   Piranha.Application..ctor() in
>   c:\Proj\GitHub\Piranha-2.2\Piranha\Application.cs:105
>   Piranha.Application..cctor() in
>   c:\Proj\GitHub\Piranha-2.2\Piranha\Application.cs:25

Please take special note of the last 2 lines of the stack, Piranha.Application..ctor() in c:\Proj\GitHub\Piranha-2.2\Piranha\Application.cs:105
   Piranha.Application..cctor() in c:\Proj\GitHub\Piranha-2.2\Piranha\Application.cs:25. 
It can't find the .cs files in c:\Proj\GitHub\Piranha-2.2 ?????

Just to confirm it wasn't me doing something stupid, i have followed the steps to add it to an empty MVC c# project, same result.

Am i doing something wrong or is the Nuget wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The AutoMapper reference was missing from Piranha.Core 2.2.4. Update to 2.2.4.1 and it should work!

**EDIT**

The reason for those file references you're seeing is that the .pdb files were included in the binary package. Those files points to the physical location on my hard drive when I compiled the package. You are seeing them because you are getting another exception (look at the stack trace) and VS are trying to debug the code.

The loader exception is thrown within MEF when scanning the assemblies in Bin for Piranha extensions. This can be caused by some other dll having references that can't be resolved. Others have had similar problems in the past with some Telerik components. What other external components are you using in your application?

Regards

Håkan

Comment: Thanks, Hakan but i have already added automapper, that's not the issue i'm getting. The issue is that VS2013 is looking for the files:
c:\Proj\GitHub\Piranha-2.2\Piranha\Application.cs:105 Piranha.Application..cctor() in c:\Proj\GitHub\Piranha-2.2\Piranha\Application.cs:25.
This folder structure does not exist and therefore throws an exception of :
[ReflectionTypeLoadException: Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.]

Comment: Please take a look at my edit, the files you mention has nothing to do with the exception